# Github workflow schedule wont run?

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow which I want to run as a schedule job. But its also run based on another workflow is success or not. As now its not running as schedule but it works if the other workflow is success.

My workflow:

```
name: Security

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["My other workflow"]
    types:
      - completed
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 3 * * *'

env:
  IMAGE: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}
  GITHUB_USERNAME: x-access-token
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  SNYK_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SNYK_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  app-dependencies-vulnerabilities:
    name: Scan for vulnerability
    if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Running snyk
        uses: snyk/actions/gradle@master
        with:
          command: monitor
          args: --org=myorg --project-name=${{ github.repository }} --remote-repo-url=https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git
          json: true
```

I think this workflow is not running as excepted schedule job because I have this conditon? `if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'`, am I right? How can I make it run as schedule AND based on the other workflow is success or not?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "AND"? Only if both conditions are true? That's not possible. Each trigger stands on it's own. Having multiple triggers `on:` means the workflow is executed wheh ANY of them happens -- not when ALL happen. What you could do for your case is trigger on schedule and then use the API to check if the last run of the other workflow is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. To check if your workflow is being triggered via a cron job (scheduled event), you may do:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'schedule' }}
```

In your case, your if condition should look:

```yaml
if: ${{ (github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success') || (github.event_name == 'schedule') }}
```